# XPath to select following-sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath

This is the code that I currently have:

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<section>
<span name="merchant">ABZ</span>
</section>
<section>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" name="edit"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" name="delete"></span>
</section>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
<div class="add-item bottom" name="new-merchant">
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
xpath=//span[contains(.,'ABZ')]/following-sibling::section/span[@name='edit']
xpath=//span[contains(.,'ABZ')]/following-sibling::span[1]
```

I am using selenium, and I want it to click on the edit button that is right after the ABZ `span`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This xpath worked for me in Chrome, using your html:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'ABZ')]/../following-sibling::section/span[@name='edit']
```

**Edit**

The `..` means to go up a level.  The `..` takes the selector from `span` to `section`.  Then the `following-sibling` finds the `section` after the parent `section` of your matching `span`.

Your original selector was matching `span`, then looking for a `following-sibling` to `span`.

Comment: Yes that worked for me as well adding the "/../following" does that have a meaning because I haven't seen other paths with that

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer above, both the expressions below will work well.

```
//span[contains(text(), 'ABZ')]/following::section/span[@name='edit']
```

OR

```
//span[contains(text(), 'ABZ')]/../following-sibling::section/span[@name='edit']
```

Notably, the axis following will pick each node following the context node while the axis following-sibling will only pick the sibling nodes to the context node.