# How to select an element based on other element in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm newby  in selenium automation.

I have one scenario where I have to click on a button based on some title. but the button element looking same for all all rows.
This is the image:
[image]

this is html for the same-

```
<tr class="odd gradeX">
<td class="hide"></td>
<td>My sample Test</td>
<td> Priyank pareek </td>
<td style="width:50px;text-align:center;">01/11/2017</td>
<td style="width:50px;text-align:center;"> Approved </td>
<td style="width:50px;text-align:center;">
<td style="width:100px;">
<a class="btn btnReject red btn-sm btn-outline sbold uppercase" href="javascript:;" onclick="updateTest(this)" data-status="0" data-gui="6438C99F-E166-49DA-8B89-DD0E2EF33A62" title="Reject">
</td>
</tr>
```

How can i click on the reject button ? please help me

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021830/xpath-to-select-following-sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate using following `xpath` -

```
//td[text()='My sample Test']/following-sibling::td/a[@title='Reject']
```

Explanation :-

Find the `td` tag which having text as 'My sample Test'
`following-sibling` used to navigate the sibling which have reject button

Comment: I would wrap this in a function and pass in the test title to click the reject button. That would make the code easier to reuse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below `XPath`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Reject']"));
```

or `CSS` selector

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Reject']"));
```

If these selectors still matches multiple elements, try:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[text()='My sample Test']]//a[@title='Reject']"));
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but I have all button with the same title

Answer (score 0):

You can search using class name `btnReject`. In Python, I usually use `driver.getElementByClassName("btnReject").click()`. You can change them into Java to use.

Comment: in the Python bindings for selenium, there is no such WebDriver method named: `getElementByClassName`.  Perhaps you meant `find_element_by_class_name`?