# XPATH: How to target value after certain text or tag

Tags: python, html, css, xpath

I am new to using `**XPath**` and this may be a basic question. Kindly bear with me and help me in resolving the issue.

Link is [here...](https://www.medicregister.com/Patient_Care_Medical/Supplier/sid32589.htm)

I would like to target the text that comes after the **"Contact:"** text. The **"Contact:"** is wrapped in a `<b>` tag. I want to target the name-value after the `<b>` tag.

I tried this xPath experession `name = response.xpath('//div[@style="line-height: 1.5;"]/b').get()` but it only return the Contact: text. I am interested in the text after this "Contact: " text.

```
<div class="vcard">
<h2><a class="fn org" target="_blank" title="https://patientcaremedical.com" href="https://patientcaremedical.com" onclick="trackClick(32589, 0)">Patient Care Medical</a><sup>&nbsp;<font color="red" size="2"><b>New!</b></font></sup></h2>
<div style="line-height: 1.5;">
<a title="info [at] patientcaremedical [.] com" href="/Patient_Care_Medical/rfq/sid32589.htm"><b><font color="red">Click Here To EMAIL INQUIRY</font></b></a>
<br><b>Contact: </b>Michael Blanchette - Marketing Director
<br>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: I tried this xPath experession name = response.xpath('//div[@style="line-height: 1.5;"]/b').get() but it only return the Contact: text. I am interested in the text after this "Contact: " text. @AMC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath to select following-sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021830/xpath-to-select-following-sibling)

Comment: possible solution: `response.xpath('//div[@style="line-height: 1.5;"]')[0].text_content().split("Contact: ")[1].strip()` . This text node is not related to any tag. You may also try `response.xpath('//div[@style="line-height: 1.5;"]/text()')` and then filter received list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//div//div[@style="line-height: 1.5;"]/normalize-space(text()[3])
```

or possibly:

```
//div//div[@style="line-height: 1.5;"]//text()[preceding-sibling::br][1]
```